# running single specific scalatest in intellij idea

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

**Updated Below with full code and isolated issue**

I am currently using intellij 14 ultimate, if I have the following code (scalatest 2.2.6, WordSpec, scala 2.11.8):

```
  "this code" when {

    "doing this" should {

      "know what is true" in {
        true shouldBe true
      }

      "know what is false" in {
        false shouldBe false
    }
  }
```

In intellij idea ultimate 14 (no extra configuration) if I right click on the line `"know what is true" in {`, it and choose `run test`, it only runs this one test

I just upgraded to 2016.1 ultimate (and tried 2016.2 RC) and this no longer works.  If I click on just one test, it only runs all tests in the file.

How do I fix this in 2016.x?

**EDIT BELOW**

If I am NOT using a tag it allows me to run just the single selected test, but if I AM using a tag, even when I select a specific test to run, it always runs ALL tests in the file - this works fine in Intellij 14.

```
object TestTag extends Tag("com.me.test.tag")

class TestingSpec extends WordSpec with Matchers {

  "these tests allow single test to run" when {

    "doing this" should {

      "know what is true" in {
        true shouldBe true
      }

      "know what is false" in {
        false shouldBe false
      }
    }
  }

  "these tests DO NOT allow single test to run" when {

    "doing this" should {

      "know what is true" taggedAs TestTag in {
        true shouldBe true
      }

      "know what is false" taggedAs TestTag in {
        false shouldBe false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a command called `Run Context Configuration` you can find it by pressing `cmd+shift+a` and typing "Run Context Configuration". This will run the test under your cursor.

If you put the cursor into the `when` block it will run all the tests in that block.

Alternatively there is a `Debug Context Configuration` that does the same thing except with the Debugger attached.

You can map those actions to whatever keymap you want in the Settings > Keymap

Comment: the cmd+shift+a does not work as outlined above in the edit

Comment: `cmd+shift+a` is just a way of running commands by name, is that what is not working for you, or is it the command that you run with it that is not working?

Comment: `cmd+shift+a+"Run Contect Configuration"` and `^+shift+F10` and `right-mouse-click-Run-test` all do the same thing.  They run all the tests if I AM using tags, they only run the one selected test if I am NOT using tags.  The same code running one selected test using tags works fine in Intellij Idea 14

Comment: Hm then that's weird, I'm using scalatest with tags as well and everything works for me. I'm assuming you are placing your cursor inside the test body curly braces before invoking the command, right?